# Some characters are more closed to each other than other characters on website

Tags: css, width, spacing

I have the strange problem that some characters stick to each other whereas other characters have more space between the other one.

That strange thing does not happen on all PCs. Could it be something with my monitor or does it have something to do with my CSS?
Since this problem does appear on all monitors at the same time, I cannot believe it has something to do with the CSS.

Maybe someone of you already had the same strange behaviour?

Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no way to answer this without more information.  Does the problem occur with just one website? all websites? all browsers or just one? Just a particular portion of a site, or maybe just on a specific font? (If it's a font, is that font installed on that particular machine, or is it installed on the working machines but not the problematic one?) Do multiple computers have the problem or just one specific machine?   Is the problem machine(s) running an unusual OS or browser?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, could be too little information to get a complete answer. The problem only occurs with the IE, I am only using this one and the website ( it is an internal website ) has been written for the IE. Multiple computers have the problem but not always on the same position! We use Windows 7. - But I would say a specific font is a good hint, I will take a look at that.